# Winforms - How to create new tab and TabPage from current form to MainWindow form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a `MainWindow` form which contains `TabControl` component where dynamicly on click on menuItem I create a new tab and `TabPage`. The new created `TabPage` contains a new `Form`.

The new opened `TabPage`, which contains the new `Form` en.`Products` have `DataGridView` with products list. When I double click on a cell in the `DataGridview` from `Products` form I want to open new tabPage to `Mainwindow`.

[image]

`dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick` -> open new tab in main window

In `MainWindow` I create:

```
private void ProductListToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProductForm = f = new Form();

    CreateTabPage(f);
}

private void CreateTabPage(Form form)
{
    form.TopLevel = false;

    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
    tabPage.Text = form.Text;
    tabPage.Controls.Add(form);

    mainWindowTabControl.Controls.Add(tabPage);
    mainWindowTabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage;

    form.Show();
}
```

From `Product` form I want to send data to `MainWindow` form to create new `TabPage` which is already defined in `MainWindow`.

```
public partial class Product: Form
{
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         // create new tab page to MainWindow form
    }
}
```

I am not using `MDI` and I think this is impossible without creating a new `MainWindow` instance and pass parameters. In my case the `MainWindow` is already opened, if I close `MainWindow` all will be closed.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property on you MainWindow that exposes the mainWindowTabControl as a property

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TabControl MainTabControl
{
  get 
  {
     return mainWindowTabControl;
  }
}
```

Now, have a property on your `Product` form, `MainFormRef`, so when you create instance of your `Product` form, pass reference of your MainWindow to it:

```
Product p = new Product();
p.MainFormRef = this;
```

Now use this to add new tabs:

```
public partial class Product: Form
{
    public Form MainFormRef { get; set; }
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         // create new tab page to MainWindow form
         TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
         tabPage.Text = form.Text;
         tabPage.Controls.Add(form);

         MainFormRef.MainTabControl.Controls.Add(tabPage);
         MainFormRef.MainTabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage;
    }
}
```